# QFileDialog: add suffix after selecting file

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

I need to add suffix to selected filename in `QFileDialog` with `QFileDialog::AcceptSave` accept mode. For example, after selecting "1.txt" file in QFileDialog edit should be select "1_suffix.txt". It should be added before file accepting, because I need the user to have the ability to change the filename before applying file.

code:

```
m_dialog.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog::AcceptSave);
m_dialog.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
m_dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::AnyFile);
m_dialog.setDefaultSuffix("_suffix");
if(m_dialog.exec() == QFileDialog::Accept)
{
    setPath(m_dialog.selectedFiles()[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, a `QFileDialog` is displaying the platform file dialog. To get the behavior you want, you'd need to use platform-specific mechanisms; Qt doesn't implement such functionality.

If you're using the non-native file dialog, you could inspect its structure to find the widget(s) you're after, filter relevant events on them, and inject the behavior you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try extending QFileDialog and subscribe to QFileDialog signals

```
  void fileSelected(QString file)
  void currentChanged(QString path)
```

It can be a start.

Comment: QFileDialog emit this signals after closing File Dialog.